# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dio

I am using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#examples) package

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
        'ra_id': '2',
        'limit': '7',
      'offset' : '0',
     
      });
      final response = await dio.post('url', data: formData);
      print(response);
```

I am getting this error :

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Response:

```
 {
      "success": true,
      "total_records": 2,
      "result": [
        {
          "s_no": 1,
          "date_time": "11 Jan 2022 1:47 PM",
          
        },
        {
          "s_no": 2,
          "date_time": "11 Jan 2022 1:46 PM"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Mycode:

```
 List<MyResult> tList = new List();
      print(response);
      for (int i = 0; i < response.data['result'].length ; i++) { //error here
        tList.add(response.data['result'][i]);
      }
```

Comment: Maybe try like `var data = json.decode(response.data);// I am not sure it should be response.data or response.body        for (int i = 0; i < data['result'].length ; i++)`

Comment: your data is come from  api

Comment: What package you are using? `http.dart`?

Comment: I am using dio.

Comment: It's important to be mentioned. Update your question with a `dio` package link. I will edit my answer soon

Comment: Debug the `response.data['result']` body. If it's really a string, just `json.decode` it as @kkweb mentioned earlier. I don't know really why it's happens, I did the same thing in my code, and it works fine `response.data['something']`.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' getting this i try to print  json.decode(response.data)